# Certain number on reference in text

Tags: natbib, sorting

I am using `natbib` with `unsrtnat` for processing bibliography for my thesis. I must prepare short summary of my thesis (about 35 pages out of ~200). It won't include literature overview just summary of my results. I have to include some (about 10%) of cited reference at the end and I want to preserve numbering from thesis text. Something like this:

```
In thesis bibliography section:
[1] Article 1
[2] Article 2
[3] Article 3
[4] Article 4
[5] Article 5
At the end of summary it should be:
[2] Article 2
[4] Article 4
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a (not so dirty) manual way to do it.  Let's say that your full thesis is in `thesis.tex`.  It should contain something like:

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
...
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{annbib}
```

and when you compile it, you should obtain a `thesis.bbl` file with your full bibliography.  To make a working example, suppose that this full bibliography contains the following:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{5}
\providecommand{\natexlab}[1]{#1}
\providecommand{\url}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\expandafter\ifx\csname urlstyle\endcsname\relax
  \providecommand{\doi}[1]{doi: #1}\else
  \providecommand{\doi}{doi: \begingroup \urlstyle{rm}\Url}\fi

\bibitem[Tennent(1976)]{tennent-1976-dspl}
R.~D. Tennent.
\newblock The denotational semantics of programming languages.
\newblock \emph{Communications of the ACM}, 19\penalty0 (8):\penalty0 437--453,
  August 1976.

\bibitem[Tennent(1991)]{tennent-1991-spl}
R.~D. Tennent.
\newblock \emph{Semantics of Programming Languages}.
\newblock Englewood Cliffs, NJ, 1991.

\bibitem[Scott and Strachey(1971)]{scott-1971-tmscl}
D.~Scott and C.~Strachey.
\newblock Towards a mathematical semantics for computer languages.
\newblock In \emph{Proceedings of the Symposium on Computers and Automata},
  pages 19--46, Brooklyn, NY, 1971. Polytechnic Press.

\bibitem[Gunter(1992)]{gunter-1992-splst}
C.~A. Gunter.
\newblock \emph{Semantics of Programming Languages: Structures and Techniques}.
\newblock Foundations of Computing Series. 1992.

\bibitem[Mitchell(1996)]{mitchell-1996-fpl}
J.~C. Mitchell.
\newblock \emph{Foundations for Programming Languages}.
\newblock 1996.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Then, you can quite easily use a subset of this bibliography in another document, say `summary.tex`, and preserve numbering like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\makeatletter
% keep track of citations in the summary
\let\oldcite\cite
\renewcommand\cite[2][]{%
  \expandafter\let\csname bib@#2\endcsname\strut%
  \oldcite[#1]{#2}%
}
% replacement for bibitem
\let\oldbibitem\bibitem
\renewcommand\bibitem[2][]{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname bib@#2\endcsname\relax%
    \advance\c@NAT@ctr\@ne%
    \skipbibitem%
  \else%
    \oldbibitem[#1]{#2}% 
  \fi%
}
% skip unused bibitems
\def\skipbibitem#1\par{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Summary}
Just two citations: \cite{tennent-1991-spl} and \cite{mitchell-1996-fpl}.

\input{thesis.bbl}
\end{document}
```

Notice that, for simplicity, the skipped `\bibitem`'s must necessarily end with a paragraph mark (`\par`).  Make sure your `.bbl` file conforms to that or you'll get LaTeX errors.

This is what you'll get for the working example:

[image: working example]

Comment: I'll try your proposal later today or may be tomorrow and I will give you feedback.